# Detecting when a user leaves or enters a channel with hubot

Tags: coffeescript, irc, hubot

I am trying to make Hubot detect when a user enters or leaves a channel, but so far I have been unable to actually find ANY information pertaining to this.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hubot's `Robot` class has functions `enter` and `leave` that will fire a callback you give when *any* user enters or leaves the room. That callback takes a `Response`, which has a property `message` of type `Message`, which in turn has a property `user` of type `User`.

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
   robot.enter (response) ->
     # at this point you can get the user's name with:
     # response.message.user.name
     # works the same for robot.leave
```

However, [it appears](https://github.com/nandub/hubot-irc/pull/26) that the IRC adapter for hubot doesn't currently fire the messages needed to get those functions to work.

Comment: For your future reference, I wasn't able to find any documentation about what Robot and the other classes can do, but the [in-code documentation in the hubot repo](https://github.com/github/hubot/tree/master/src)... exists.